# How to model time dependent relationships?

Tags: neo4j

What's the right way to model and iterate time dependent relationships?

For example:

- John married Elizabeth on 07/03/69 and divorced her 05/12/73; then he married Corrie on 03/18/82 and still married.
- Mark worked for IBM (certain date intervals), then MSFT (other time interval), etc.

There are many other relationships which are time dependent:

- lived in
- worked for
- reported to
- belonged to etc.

What is the right way to model these? A typical query would be to find a traversal with an "as of" parameter, e.g "Who is the spouse of John as of 01/01/74?"

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done by using indexes. Index/properties can only use primitive, so you can convert your Date object to a long value, then you can index that value. You'll have to store the index as a special [Numeric](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-lucene-extras.html) type, but after that, you can search based on a range, so you can do a "Before" or an "After" or even a "Between" type query.

Comment: makes sense. so still to model the time-dependency as a pair of from/till attributes? what's the best way to model the "forever" value? put minumum/maximum values or omit them and interpret the miss in the query?

Comment: Forever can be `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using extra nodes to represent a particular marriage or period of employment in conjunction with a [calendar subgraph](http://blog.nigelsmall.com/2012/09/modelling-dates-in-neo4j.html). For example, John's marriages could be modelled as follows:

```
(John)-[:MARRIAGE]->(John+Liz)
(Liz)-[:MARRIAGE]->(John+Liz)
(John+Liz)-[:START_DATE]->(07/03/69)
(John+Liz)-[:END_DATE]->(05/12/73)
(John)-[:MARRIAGE]->(John+Corrie)
(Corrie)-[:MARRIAGE]->(John+Corrie)
(John+Corrie)-[:START_DATE]->(03/18/82)
```

This gives you flexibility in both the number of marriages each person may undertake as well as whether an `END_DATE` exists or not.

Hope this helps

Nige

Comment: Nige, I'm not sure it's right - these nodes would be pertinent only for the two relating nodes and describe that connection which can be completely done via the relationship's attributes directly.

Comment: It's not intended to be right or wrong, merely another possible approach. It comes down to what level of abstraction you need both now and going forward: is the marriage always simply a relationship between two parties or is it an entity of its own? With a node representing the marriage you could also have rels to other relevant nodes such as the geographical location or to other people involved (e.g. witnesses or children of that union). Neo4j doesn't allow relationship endpoints to be other relationships, so that would not otherwise be possible.

Comment: Good point! If the marriage itself bears additional attributes then you're right.

Answer (score 0):

i would assume to build always two kinds of relationships for every type - lived_in_s, lived_in_e, belonged_to_s, belonged_to_e .... where the postfixes "s" and "e" represents the time of start and end of that relationships. than, querying an as of parameter could look like:

```
START n=node({John}) 
MATCH n-[r:spouse_of_s]-m, n-[?r2:spouse_of_e]-m
WHERE r2.time? < {timestamp} AND r.time > {timestamp}
RETURN m;
```

(i might have a typo in the query at r2?, i wrote it without testing)

and you might want to use the indexes @nicholas wrote about

Answer (score 0):

I usually add a timestamp with on_date attribute.

I would also recommend encoding your date in the following format YYYYMMDD. You can then easily add comparisons in your code. For instance:

John married Elizabeth on 07/03/69 and divorced her 05/12/73; then he married Corrie on 03/18/82 and still married.

if you want to know if John is married and to whom, you can simply compare the date, and get the end node.